# How to combine multiple categories in one Menu item?

Tags: menus

How do I combine multiple categories in one Menu item?

Below is two categories link

example.com/category/news/news
example.com/category/news/breakingnews

How to create a menu that show all the article in these categories?

I read a discussion [here](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/combine-multiple-categories-in-one-menu-item) but still can't understand.